# Magento update order product on observer

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to update **additional_data** field on **sales_flat_order_item** table in Magento.

For this I create a custom module

This is my Observer.php under app/code/local/Distelsa/Wedding/Models :

```
class Distelsa_Wedding_Model_Observer{

    public function AddWeddingIdToProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        $item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $item->getQuote();
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $controllerAction = $event->getControllerAction();
        $params = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams();
        $boda = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('boda');

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET additional_data = '".$params['boda']."' where item_id = ".$item->getId();
        $write->query($query);

    }
}
```

This is my config.xml:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <sales_order_save_after_wedding>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>wedding/observer</class>
                    <method>AddWeddingIdToProduct</method>
                </sales_order_save_after_wedding>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Any clue on how can I make this works?

Answer (score 0):

The `<class>` is wrong in the `config.xml` file.

The correct class in the config.xml goes like this :

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <sales_order_save_after_wedding>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>distelsa_wedding/observer</class>
                    <method>AddWeddingIdToProduct</method>
                </sales_order_save_after_wedding>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Clear the chache when you are done. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Manashvi, but that didn't work. Do you have another idea on what's wrong?